# Castle DictionaryAdapter or JSON for reading app settings with nested dictionaries

Tags: c#, json, json.net, castle, castle-dictionaryadapter

I need to read my application settings as a dictionary like this: `App1: values1, App2: values2, App3: values3`, where `values` are having properties like `Label` (string) and `EnvVar` (dictionary < string, string >).

So far I have two options:

1. Is it possible to use DictionaryAdapter to read these settings? I didn't find any clue in the documentation or on Google, the best I can do so far is retrieve a list of strings and parse the strings in the code, which I would like to avoid if possible.
2. Another way would be to use a JSON deserializer, but it seems that I can't deserialize an interface, like I can with Castle DictionaryAdapter, so I need to define both the settings interface and the class that implements it. Is there any JSON library that can deserialize an interface like Castle DictionaryAdapter does?